# Estimating constant and local volatility based on passage times

Tags: volatility, brownian-motion, estimation

Consider a Brownian motion `B_t` with **constant** instantaneous volatility `σ` and zero drift

[image]

where `t` is larger than zero and the brownian motion is equal to zero in the beginning.

We know that the increments are equal to

[image]

and satisfy

[image]

This leads to the moment condition:

[image]

For which we can estimate `σ` based on a sample of returns. This is basically the same as close-to-close / traditional volatility. However,  rather than measuring the
size of Brownian increments over a fixed time interval, we can also measure the time it takes the Brownian motion to travel a given distance up or down. This can be written as:

[image]

According to Borodin and Salminen (2002) we have the following moment condition

[image]

Again we can calculate `σ`, when we re-arrange the formula:

[image]

However, when volatility is **not constant** we can not assume that the observed passage times are identically distributed. According to this [paper](http://hermes-ir.lib.hit-u.ac.jp/hermes/ir/re/17081/gd08-034.pdf) we can apply the following method to calculate the local volatility:

Consider a fixed time grid

[image]

that consists of `N`, not necessarily equispaced, intervals. Each interval is equal to

[image]

At a given point, `t_i`, we need to look for the next passage time [image]. Since the Brownian motion is time-reversible, we can also look backwards and find the previous passage time, [image]. Visually this looks as follows:

[image]

Next, we have two independent estimators of local volatility at `t_i`, namely

[image]

and

[image]

We take the average of the two and have an estimation of the local volatility at the point `t_i`.

What I don't understand is that the `N` intervals are not *necessarily equispaced* intervals. Why is this the case? How to determine then the size of each individual interval?

Comment: Just a note: If $B(t)$ is defined as Brownian Motion with volatility $\sigma$, then the very first equation in your question should be $\int_{0}^{t}\sigma dW_t$

Comment: yes, you're correct. Thanks for pointing out. Any chance you can also help me with my final question?

Comment: Let me see if I understood the question. Are you asking why the time intervals can be non-identical? And how to compute them?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with non-identical, I am focusing on non-equally sized

Comment: time intervals can be different because [day count conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention) can yield to different interval sizes. When you move from dates given in a term sheet to real numbers used for computations, you will probably get non-equally sized time intervals.